# Meaning of the words "gonna get it" in the clause

Tags: meaning

Wife and Husband just got in their car.
Wife was rushing her husband not to get late to a movie theater while her husband was trying to start the car. He can't get his car started multiple times because the car won't start. Do the words in bold mean to start the car or there is something else?

> Wife: We got to get there before it's too late.
> Husband: I **AM GONNA GET IT** just a sec.

Comment: "Gonna" is poorly eninciated "going to". That is, he, "is going to get the car started."

Comment: Does (which you've misspelt as 'Dose') is singular. You should say "Do the words in bold...".

Comment: Yes, "gonna get it" means he is going to complete the thing his wife is fussing at him about.